# Postback With Partial views-ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Jquery for displaying multiple tabs in MVC 3, based on the tutorial.[Tutorial](http://www.kevgriffin.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/23/using-jquery-tabs-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views-for-ajax-goodness/)

I am loading the data for various tabs based on the partial views using the Jquery.

All the partial views are with the attribute `[HttpGet]`.  I want to place a button in the partial view and when I click on that button it should call service and submit the data to server.

Could I do that using a partial view with attribute `[HttpPost]`? I tried that but it complains saying that there cannot be two methods with same Name.

are partial views does not support [HttpPost]? Am I doing something wrong?

If you have done in other way to complete these kind of task please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Questions like this should provide at least your controller code.

Comment: David you do not need to mark it down, I hope you been preety smart, I asked for help and if you have asked me I would have provided the code, but you don't need to just mark it down

Comment: @StewiFG I didn't mark it down. Someone else probably marked it down because you didn't provide any code. So, where did your profile's 3 downvotes come from today? Ironically, I just received 3 downvotes on completely unrelated questions in about a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you may have attributed your Action methods with `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`, they need different parameter lists. In my example below, you will need to post a `string` named `someData` in order to receive a response.

So, this is valid:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(string someData)
{
    return View();
}
```

And, this is **not** valid:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```